# Using files as IPC in Linux?

Tags: linux, ipc

We're writing a program that haves 2 processes. One process reads data from a serial device, and the other process consumes this data and sends it to the network.

I've been researching and there are many ways to communicate these 2 processes, seems that the best choice would be pipes or message queues. I like queues, because the network process is unreliable or relative slow compared to the serial, plus queues allow to share data types instead of raw bytes stream.

We also need a log to monitor every IPC communication, so we thought, Why not use a shared file? So proc 1 writes to the file, proc 2 reads each line of the file and marks each line as sent, when it processes it.We could use file lockings for this.

The file approach could serve both as a buffering and logging.

Having this file would be very valuable for business logic.

So.. Should we go for message, pipes, or files?

PS. Device in this case runs Linux 2.6.3 on ARM device, and Hard Drive is just an SD card.

Comment: Message-queuing software often logs the messages regardless of medium. You could, for example, use shared memory to communicate between the processes and a log file to store the message history. Your MQ would handle this automatically for you.

Comment: @chrisaycock What happens if the MQ grows very large due to network failure?

Comment: Use [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) (or some event loop) and [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch So just use a pipe?

Comment: Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and also [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html), [eventfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html) and [signalfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html) etc... You probably need some event loop (either your own with `poll`, or [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html), [libevent](http://libevent.org/) etc..

Answer (score 0):

In your case it might be also suitable to use [mmap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap) and flush the buffer to file system when hibernating or closing an application. Implementation might be more complex compared to sockets or pipes.